# Confirmation popup doesn't appear before deleting a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of records in a webpage. One column contains a link to delete each record. I want the browser to ask if the user is sure they want to delete the record before proceeding.

I have used the following code to create the link in each row:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',  
             :action => 'delete',  
             :id => item,  
             :method => :delete,  
             :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?' %>
```

At present this app simply deletes the record without any confirmation popup appearing.

I am using Rails 2.3.18. After researching this all I can find is instructions to use the code above. Or adding code to include the application.js but this is doing no good since there is nothing in it yet, in which case I'm not sure what to include.

Comment: Try this `<%= link_to 'Delete', :action => 'delete', :id => item, :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'} %>`

Comment: I have tried that line. The browser is given an error page saying there's a compile error because it was expected a different symbol on the line the "data: { confirm..." part is. I played around with the code, and changed that part to ":data => { :confirm => 'you sure?' }" and the listing page now renders. Unfortunately, when I click on the "delete" link it deletes the row without asking for confirmation.

Comment: make sure your browser is not blocking alerts. this might also be the reason. To make sure close browser and start another session

Comment: I've closed the browser and tried again. I was using Chrome, and now I've tried it with Firefox too. Still the same problem.

Comment: Are there any gems I need to install? Or any other javascript references I should consider?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',:id => item, :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'} %>
```

More info **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)**

If the above didn't work,then try the below

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',:id => item, :method => :delete, :onclick=> "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')" %>
```

Comment: The use of :onclick doesn't bring up a confirmation popup either.

Comment: Using the second example results in the following html in the browser:   
     <a href="/manager/delete_item/12?method=delete&amp;onclick=javascript%3A+return+confirm%28%27Are+you+sure+you+want+to+delete+this+item%3F%27%29%3B">Delete</a>

I'm guessing there is something amiss elsewhere, given how this code you have given me is so ubiquitously the solution to the problem.

Comment: @radiobrain77 I think it is generating the correct HTML.Did it worked for you?

Comment: It still doesn't work. The javascript call to confirm seems to be added as part of the href in the anchor, so it is getting passed back to the server side, and not being called.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, there is no action 'delete', it is 'destroy'. And also you don't need to specify action name, rails will automatically route to action based on request method.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',item,:method => :delete,:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?' %>
```

Comment: The action is actually called 'delete_item', and by taking it out the page merely reloads. It isn't automatically routing because there isn't a delete method filled out in the controller.

Comment: Ok then you have to specify action path like delete_item_path(id) or using legacy :action, :controller mechanism. Also make sure javascript is enabled in your browser and you have not blocked popups. Also verify you not installed any add-blocker plugin in your browser. ad-blocker also prevents popup windows to display.

Comment: The action and controller mechanisms work fine. The item gets deleted just fine. However I need a confirmation first. Also, I've already checked the popups situation. Chrome isn't blocking them.